# ASP.NET C# (3.5) Membership, How to get Approved Users only?

Tags: asp.net, filter, membership

I need a list of "Approved" Users only, but don't know how to figure it out.

```
lstUsersNotInRole.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers(); // Get Approved Users Only!?!
lstUsersNotInRole.DataBind();
```

Any kind help would be highly appreciated.

Kardo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of delving into the database and altering/creating stored procedures (and since you didn't specify which database you are using), you can do this by using Linq. Try this:

```
Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().Where(u => u.IsApproved == true).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your so perfect and simple answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the approved users in your stored procedure and return the result to your application.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Membership_GetActiveUsersInRoles

    @RoleName nvarchar(256)

AS

    BEGIN

        DECLARE @RoleId uniqueidentifier

        SELECT @RoleId = RoleId
        FROM dbo.aspnet_Roles
        WHERE LOWER(@RoleName) = LoweredRoleName

        SELECT u.UserName, u.UserId
        FROM dbo.aspnet_Users u, dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles ur, dbo.aspnet_Membership m
        WHERE
        u.UserId = m.UserId AND
        u.UserId = ur.UserId AND
        @RoleId = ur.RoleId and
        m.IsApproved = 'true'
         -- You can also specify m.IsLockedOut = 'false' for other purposes

END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `SqlMembershipProvider`, you could select them manually, either as plain sql-statement(e.g. via `ADO.NET`) or by creating a custom stored-procedure which  also supports paging and the `ApplicationId` and where you can parameterize `IsApproved`.

```
SELECT  m.IsApproved, u.UserName, 
        m.Email, m.PasswordQuestion, m.Comment, 
        m.CreateDate, m.LastLoginDate, u.LastActivityDate,
        m.LastPasswordChangedDate, u.UserId, 
        m.IsLockedOut, m.LastLockoutDate
FROM   dbo.aspnet_Membership m, dbo.aspnet_Users u
WHERE  u.UserId = m.UserId 
AND    m.IsApproved = @IsApproved
ORDER BY u.UserName
```

Just have  a look at `dbo.aspnet_Membership_GetAllUsers`, copy paste the relevant parts and modify it accordingly.